# Making 90% similar code for 20 different objects

Tags: c#, object-oriented, generics

Basically, I have 20 very similar objects and most importantly I want to do the same thing for all of them.

This is the `ImportProcessor` class for `AutomobileExpense` (`AutomobileExpenseDataImportProcessor`). And in this scenario I would need another 19 `ImportProcessor` classes for the other similar objects.

I have made common logic with generic methods or not in the base class. The only things I cannot make generic or without some deep reflection logic are:

- the enums in the constructor
- the repository in the constructor
- the specific Object properties in if and else statements, method which returns `Guid -> this.ProcessDebt()` and his second and third arguments `xrefDebt.DebtsAutomobileExpense` and `converted.DebtsAutomobileExpense`

```
public class AutomobileExpenseDataImportProcessor : BaseDebtDataImportProcessor
    {
        private GenericRepository<DebtsAutomobileExpense> _repo;
        public AutomobileExpenseDataImportProcessor(MyCompanyIUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IAuthenticationUserSession user, SystemDecision systemDecisons, params Expression<Func<XRefClientBusiness, object>>[] include)
            : base(unitOfWork, user, systemDecisons, include)
        {
            this._repo = this._unitOfWork.DebtsAutomobileExpenseRepository;
            this._objectType = ObjectType.DebtsAutomobileExpense;
            this._importObjType = ImportObjectType.DebtAutomobileExpense;
            this._flag = ClientDebtFlag.AutomobileExpense;
        }

        protected override void ImportDebt(XRefClientBusiness xrefDb, XRefClientBusinessDebt converted)
        {
            if (this.IsDebtForUpdate(xrefDb, this._flag)) // Update
            {
                var xrefDebt = xrefDb.XRefClientBusinessDebts.FirstDefault(f => f.DebtSection.HasFlag(this._flag));
                Guid updatedId = this.ProcessDebt(xrefDb, xrefDebt.DebtsAutomobileExpense, converted.DebtsAutomobileExpense, this._flag, this._repo);

                this.AddUpdatedObjectToResult(updatedId, this._flag.ToString(),this._importObjType);
                this.AddSystemDecisionObject(updatedId, this._objectType, ActivityAction.Modified);
            }
            else // Insert
            {
                Guid insertedId = this.ProcessDebt(xrefDb, null, converted.DebtsAutomobileExpense, this._flag, this._repo);

                this.AddCreatedObjectToResult(insertedId, this._flag.ToString(), this._importObjType);
                this.AddSystemDecisionObject(insertedId, this._objectType, ActivityAction.Added);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have set up everything needed to change in the constructur, except two properties in the If Else statement. Imagine when I create the another 19 super similar cases, I will update the constructor enums and 3 places inside the If else statement like this:

```
        {
            this._repo = this._unitOfWork.DebtsAutomobileExpenseRepository; // Update
            this._objectType = ObjectType.DebtsAutomobileExpense; // Update
            this._importObjType = ImportObjectType.DebtAutomobileExpense; // Update
            this._flag = ClientDebtFlag.AutomobileExpense; 
        }
```

and

```
// update second and third arguments (after the xrefDebt. and coverted. )
Guid updatedId = this.ProcessDebt(xrefDb, xrefDebt.DebtsAutomobileExpense, converted.DebtsAutomobileExpense, this._flag, this._repo);
```

I think this is the best approach, because it is clearer, the approach when every object deal with its own insert/update logic sound way more OOP correct.

But anyway, do you think there is a better way?

I was thinking for example, trying to make one generic `ImportProcessor` class, instead of 20, which will be called with all the needed enums in the constructor. The correct repository again in the constructor and for this part `xrefDebt.DebtsAutomobileExpense` to use some kind of reflection logic to take the correct property, but that sounds a bit confusing.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Is it better now? @Mast

Comment: The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code.

Comment: @Jackie your title might be closest to the first example on the [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page under the list of examples that follow this text: _"Here are some examples of titles that are unacceptable because they are too generic:"_ Please see examples that follow the text "_The norm is to summarize the goal of the code in the title. Some typical titles are:_"

Comment: Ok, very helpfull! I have recieved 3 comments about question title and none about the real question. Sorry but this is not quite helpfull. I think the second title is OK. It is again generic, but otherwise i have to go too deep in details and write really long Title. However..